# Making a list of functions with any arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I would like to try to have a list of void function pointers with any arguments. So far, I managed to make a list of void functions that take in particular arguments, but I would like to extend this so that I have one list for all functions. The below code has been my attempt at doing this. If I swap `...` to `int*, int` it runs, but if I don't, I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'void saveFunction(char *,callback_function)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(int *,int)' to 'callback_function'
Test2.cpp(23): note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
Test2.cpp(15): note: see declaration of 'saveFunction'
```

Is something like I describe above possible to do?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <initializer_list>

const int SIZE = 5;
const int LIMIT = 100;

typedef void (*callback_function)(int*, int); // type for conciseness

static int counter = 0;
static int numberOfSetupFunctions = 0;
static char** functionNames = new char*[LIMIT];
static callback_function functionPointers[LIMIT];

void saveFunction(char* name, callback_function ptr){
    functionNames[numberOfSetupFunctions] = name;
    functionPointers[numberOfSetupFunctions] = ptr;
    numberOfSetupFunctions++;
    printf("function (%s) has an address of (%p)\n", name, ptr);
}

void dbl(int* a, int b){
    saveFunction(__FUNCTION__, dbl);

    for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
        a[i] *= 2;
}

int main(){
    int arr[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n================\n");

    dbl(arr, SIZE);

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n================\n");

    int* arr2 = new int[5]{5, 10, 15};
    functionPointers[0](arr2, 3);

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        printf("%i, ", arr2[i]);
    printf("\n================\n");
}
```

Comment: " If I swap `...` to `int*, int` it runs, but if I don't, I get the following error:" - It's because the ellipsis (`...`) is part of the signature of the function; the function pointers are incompatible.

Comment: What do you want to do with your list of function pointer? You cannot know how to call them (as each might accept different arguments)...

Comment: Have you considered using `std::function` and templates?